# Flying as far as somewhere or to somewhere?

Tags: adjectives

The following excerpt is taken from an article of VOA Health report "Africans Flock to South Africa in Search of the Perfect Body".

> How far would you go for a perfect body? Many people these days are **going as far as South Africa** to get their version of perfection. People from across Africa and the world come for so-called surgery "safaris".

My question is about the highlighted part "... going as far as South Africa ...".
Should it not be "... going as far as to South Africa ..."?
Or are both correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can go *to* South Africa, or

You can go *as far as* South Africa.

Both *to* and *as far as* are prepositions.

EDIT: there is a difference in meaning.

If you fly *to* South Africa, then your destination and hopefully your safe arrival is South Africa.

If you fly *as far as* South Africa, this means you will fly up to and including the distance it takes to fly to South Africa. But you could fly to a closer destination instead, say Egypt, if that was closer to you than South Africa. It is similar to saying I will fly *as far as* 1000 miles. You are saying you will fly up to 1000 miles (as far as) but perhaps you will actually fly less than 1000. A thousand is your limit. *The maximum distance* you will fly. *As far as* you will fly.

See examples of *as far as* [here under Number 2](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/far_1).

Thanks to Edwin Ashworth for pointing out that *as far as* is a compound preposition.

Comment: They're both adverbials and prepositional phrases. 'As far as' is a compound preposition. See [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20far%20as).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth thanks for pointing out that *as far as* is a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

Stripping back to basics,

> They went to South Africa.

and

> They went as far as South Africa.

are obviously very similar constructions.

No one would give any different analysis of 'to South Africa' than 'prepositional phrase headed by the preposition *to*; functioning adverbially'.

Modern analysis accepts that there are multi-word prepositions (often labelled 'compound' or 'complex') like 'out of [the house]'  – cf 'into the house', 'in front of', 'on top of'. 'As far as' when used similarly is included, as [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20far%20as) states. (If you're worried that this is only claimed to apply to the metaphorical usage by M-W, that's an omission; the Fowler reference below claims 'as far as London' to be prep + noun.) So the two examples are virtually identical grammatically.

Doubling prepositions is a different matter. It isn't forbidden as such, but is quite rare, and arguably the first one then sometimes switches to an adverb.

> Look down along the road.
>
> It ran out from under the sofa.

But with 'as far as to' [South Africa], I'd say it was unnecessary, clumsy and arguably ungrammatical.

Comment: What definition? I was merely giving evidence that 'as far as' is considered a multi-word preposition. If you insist on an example of a literal usage (though I suspect a metaphorical usage predicates a literal one): 'the literal sense ... _as far as London_' occurs in [H.W. Fowler (1858–1933).  The King’s English, 2nd ed.  1908. 
Chapter II. Syntax PREPOSITIONS](http://www.bartleby.com/116/217.html.). Happy?

Comment: I've augmented in line with your suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

"going as far as" is correct, though it does seem to violate the usual rule "going . . . to" .  In a sense, "as far as" takes the place of "to". It is an intentionally longer way to say it, for the purpose of stressing that the trip might be a long one.           .
Similar phrasing is used figuratively: "I would go so far as to say your pink socks do not complement your green pants." (here of course the "to" is not a preposition; it is part of the infinitive " to say".)